# Framework for building Swing UI in a more modular fashion

Tags: java, swing, gui

Swing code may be hard to read. As is, it's not inherently visually modular, and component composition is not immediately clear. To address that, I created a simple framework called `UIBuilder` which, in my opinion, makes Swing code easier to write and read. Besides, it provides some nice implicit settings, like frame centering, so you no longer have to bother with those. Here's an example. I purposefully took [someone else's Swing code](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator/java/example) since I want this post to be about my framework code rather than UI. **`UIBuilder` is 100% my own creation so I don't believe the "it must be your code" rule is in any way violated**

### Without `UIBuilder`

###### components.Component

```java
public interface Component {
    void setMediator(Mediator mediator);
    String getName();
}
```

###### components.AddButton

```java
public class AddButton extends JButton implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;

    public AddButton() {
        super("Add");
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        mediator.addNewNote(new Note());
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "AddButton";
    }
}
```

###### components.DeleteButton

```java
public class DeleteButton extends JButton  implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;

    public DeleteButton() {
        super("Del");
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        mediator.deleteNote();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "DelButton";
    }
}
```

###### components.Filter

```java
public class Filter extends JTextField implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;
    private ListModel listModel;

    public Filter() {}

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processComponentKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        String start = getText();
        searchElements(start);
    }

    public void setList(ListModel listModel) {
        this.listModel = listModel;
    }

    private void searchElements(String s) {
        if (listModel == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (s.equals("")) {
            mediator.setElementsList(listModel);
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listModel.getSize(); i++) {
            notes.add((Note) listModel.getElementAt(i));
        }
        DefaultListModel<Note> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (Note note : notes) {
            if (note.getName().contains(s)) {
                listModel.addElement(note);
            }
        }
        mediator.setElementsList(listModel);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Filter";
    }
}
```

###### components.List

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class List extends JList implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;
    private final DefaultListModel LIST_MODEL;

    public List(DefaultListModel listModel) {
        super(listModel);
        this.LIST_MODEL = listModel;
        setModel(listModel);
        this.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Hide(this));
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void addElement(Note note) {
        LIST_MODEL.addElement(note);
        int index = LIST_MODEL.size() - 1;
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
        mediator.sendToFilter(LIST_MODEL);
    }

    public void deleteElement() {
        int index = this.getSelectedIndex();
        try {
            LIST_MODEL.remove(index);
            mediator.sendToFilter(LIST_MODEL);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {}
    }

    public Note getCurrentElement() {
        return (Note)getSelectedValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "List";
    }

    private class Hide implements Runnable {
        private List list;

        Hide(List list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                    mediator.hideElements(true);
                } else {
                    mediator.hideElements(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

###### components.SaveButton

```java
public class SaveButton extends JButton implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;

    public SaveButton() {
        super("Save");
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        mediator.saveChanges();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "SaveButton";
    }
}
```

###### components.TextBox

```java
public class TextBox extends JTextArea implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processComponentKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        mediator.markNote();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "TextBox";
    }
}
```

###### components.Title

```java
public class Title extends JTextField implements Component {
    private Mediator mediator;

    @Override
    public void setMediator(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processComponentKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        mediator.markNote();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Title";
    }
}
```

###### mediator.Mediator

```java
public interface Mediator {
    void addNewNote(Note note);
    void deleteNote();
    void getInfoFromList(Note note);
    void saveChanges();
    void markNote();
    void clear();
    void sendToFilter(ListModel listModel);
    void setElementsList(ListModel list);
    void registerComponent(Component component);
    void hideElements(boolean flag);
    void createGUI();
}
```

###### mediator.Editor

```java
public class Editor implements Mediator {
    private Title title;
    private TextBox textBox;
    private AddButton add;
    private DeleteButton del;
    private SaveButton save;
    private List list;
    private Filter filter;

    private JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title:");
    private JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Text:");
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Add or select existing note to proceed...");
  
    /**
     * Here the registration of components by the mediator.
     */
    @Override
    public void registerComponent(Component component) {
        component.setMediator(this);
        switch (component.getName()) {
            case "AddButton":
                add = (AddButton)component;
                break;
            case "DelButton":
                del = (DeleteButton)component;
                break;
            case "Filter":
                filter = (Filter)component;
                break;
            case "List":
                list = (List)component;
                this.list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionEvent -> {
                    Note note = (Note)list.getSelectedValue();
                    if (note != null) {
                        getInfoFromList(note);
                    } else {
                        clear();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case "SaveButton":
                save = (SaveButton)component;
                break;
            case "TextBox":
                textBox = (TextBox)component;
                break;
            case "Title":
                title = (Title)component;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Various methods to handle requests from particular components.
     */
    @Override
    public void addNewNote(Note note) {
        title.setText("");
        textBox.setText("");
        list.addElement(note);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteNote() {
        list.deleteElement();
    }

    @Override
    public void getInfoFromList(Note note) {
        title.setText(note.getName().replace('*', ' '));
        textBox.setText(note.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveChanges() {
        try {
            Note note = (Note) list.getSelectedValue();
            note.setName(title.getText());
            note.setText(textBox.getText());
            list.repaint();
        } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void markNote() {
        try {
            Note note = list.getCurrentElement();
            String name = note.getName();
            if (!name.endsWith("*")) {
                note.setName(note.getName() + "*");
            }
            list.repaint();
        } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        title.setText("");
        textBox.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendToFilter(ListModel listModel) {
        filter.setList(listModel);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void setElementsList(ListModel list) {
        this.list.setModel(list);
        this.list.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void hideElements(boolean flag) {
        titleLabel.setVisible(!flag);
        textLabel.setVisible(!flag);
        title.setVisible(!flag);
        textBox.setVisible(!flag);
        save.setVisible(!flag);
        label.setVisible(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public void createGUI() {
        JFrame notes = new JFrame("Notes");
        notes.setSize(960, 600);
        notes.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        left.setSize(320, 600);
        left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        filterPanel.add(new JLabel("Filter:"));
        filter.setColumns(20);
        filterPanel.add(filter);
        filterPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 40));
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        list.setFixedCellWidth(260);
        listPanel.setSize(320, 470);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 410));
        listPanel.add(scrollPane);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        add.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
        buttonPanel.add(add);
        del.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
        buttonPanel.add(del);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        left.add(filterPanel);
        left.add(listPanel);
        left.add(buttonPanel);
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setLayout(null);
        right.setSize(640, 600);
        right.setLocation(320, 0);
        right.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        titleLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 20);
        title.setBounds(60, 5, 555, 20);
        textLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 130);
        textBox.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        textBox.setBounds(20, 80, 595, 410);
        save.setBounds(270, 535, 80, 25);
        label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        label.setBounds(100, 240, 500, 100);
        right.add(label);
        right.add(titleLabel);
        right.add(title);
        right.add(textLabel);
        right.add(textBox);
        right.add(save);
        notes.setLayout(null);
        notes.getContentPane().add(left);
        notes.getContentPane().add(right);
        notes.setResizable(false);
        notes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        notes.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

###### mediator.Note

```java
public class Note {
    private String name;
    private String text;

    public Note() {
        name = "New note";
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

###### Demo

```java
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mediator mediator = new Editor();

        mediator.registerComponent(new Title());
        mediator.registerComponent(new TextBox());
        mediator.registerComponent(new AddButton());
        mediator.registerComponent(new DeleteButton());
        mediator.registerComponent(new SaveButton());
        mediator.registerComponent(new List(new DefaultListModel()));
        mediator.registerComponent(new Filter());

        mediator.createGUI();
    }
}
```

### With `UIBuilder`

###### mediator.Editor

```java
// the rest is omitted

    @Override
    public void createGUI() {
        UIUtil.getUIBuilderWithLayout(() -> null)
                .withTitle("Notes")
                .withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(() -> {
                            var leftPanel = new JPanel();
                            leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                            return leftPanel;
                        })
                        .withBorder(() -> new LineBorder(Color.BLACK))
                        .withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(JPanel::new)
                                .withComponent(() -> new JLabel("Filter:"))
                                .withComponent(() -> {
                                    filter.setColumns(20);
                                    return filter;
                                })
                                .withPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 40))
                                .build())
                        .withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(JPanel::new)
                                .withComponent(() -> {
                                    list.setFixedCellWidth(260);
                                    var listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
                                    listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 410));
                                    return listScrollPane;
                                })
                                .withSize(320, 470)
                                .build())
                        .withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(() -> {
                                    var buttonPanel = new JPanel();
                                    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                                    return buttonPanel;
                                })
                                .withComponent(() -> {
                                    add.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
                                    return add;
                                })
                                .withComponent(() -> {
                                    del.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
                                    return del;
                                })
                                .build())
                        .withSize(320, 600)
                        .build())
                .withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(() -> {
                            var right = new JPanel();
                            right.setLayout(null);
                            return right;
                        })
                        .withBorder(() -> new LineBorder(Color.BLACK))
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                            label.setBounds(100, 240, 500, 100);
                            return label;
                        })
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            titleLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 20);
                            return titleLabel;
                        })
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            title.setBounds(60, 5, 555, 20);
                            return title;
                        })
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            textLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 130);
                            return textLabel;
                        })
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            textBox.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
                            textBox.setBounds(20, 80, 595, 410);
                            return textBox;
                        })
                        .withComponent(() -> {
                            save.setBounds(270, 535, 80, 25);
                            return save;
                        })
                        .withSize(640, 600)
                        .withLocation(320, 0)
                        .build())
                .withResizable(false)
                .withLocationRelativeTo(null)
                .withFrameSize(960, 600)
                .visualize();
    }
```

Now let's get to the main part, the `UIBuilder` code

### `UIBuilder` code

###### UIUtil

```java
// irrelevant constants and utilities removed

public class UIUtil {
    private static Rectangle maximumWindowBounds;

    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilder() {
        return new UIBuilder();
    }

    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilderWithLayout(@NotNull Supplier<LayoutManager> layoutSupplier) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(layoutSupplier);
        return new UIBuilder()
                .withLayout(layoutSupplier);
    }

    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilderWithContentPane(@NotNull Supplier<Container> contentPaneSupplier) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(contentPaneSupplier);
        return new UIBuilder()
                .withContentPane(contentPaneSupplier);
    }

    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilderWithLayoutAndContentPane(@NotNull Supplier<LayoutManager> layoutSupplier,
                                                                 @NotNull Supplier<Container> contentPaneSupplier) {
        Stream.of(layoutSupplier, contentPaneSupplier).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
        return new UIBuilder()
                .withLayout(layoutSupplier)
                .withContentPane(contentPaneSupplier);
    }

    public static ComponentBuilder getComponentBuilder(@NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(componentSupplier);
        return new ComponentBuilder(componentSupplier);
    }

    public static MenuBarBuilder getMenuBarBuilder() {
        return new MenuBarBuilder();
    }

    public static MenuBuilder getMenuBuilder(@NotNull String menuName) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(menuName);
        return new MenuBuilder(menuName);
    }

    public static Rectangle getMaximumWindowBounds() {
        if (maximumWindowBounds == null) {
            maximumWindowBounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        }
        return maximumWindowBounds;
    }

    private static void checkContainerSize(int width, int height) {
        Stream.of(width, height).forEach(Util::requirePositive);
/*    
I won't provide the Util class code if you don't mind: the Util.requirePositive() method is very simple and does exactly what it says. You can replace it with a simple if statement for the code to compile like so:

if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The values must be positive");
*/
        checkAgainstScreenSize(width, height);
    }

    private static void checkAgainstScreenSize(int widthOrX, int heightOrY) {
        var bounds = getMaximumWindowBounds();
        if (bounds.width < widthOrX) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values like width or X coordinate cannot be greater than screen width");
        } else if (bounds.height < heightOrY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values like height or Y coordinate cannot be greater than screen height");
        }
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class UIBuilder {
        private final JFrame frame;
        private final Rectangle maximumWindowBounds = getMaximumWindowBounds();

        {
            frame = new JFrame();
            this.withFrameSize(300, 300)
                    .withDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        private UIBuilder withLayout(@NotNull Supplier<LayoutManager> layoutSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(layoutSupplier);
            frame.setLayout(layoutSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        private UIBuilder withContentPane(@NotNull Supplier<Container> contentPaneSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(contentPaneSupplier);
            frame.setContentPane(contentPaneSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withTitle(@NotNull String title) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(title);
            frame.setTitle(title);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withComponent(@NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(componentSupplier);
            getAndAddToPane(componentSupplier);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withComponent(@NotNull String position, @NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            Stream.of(position, componentSupplier).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
            getAndAddToPane(position, componentSupplier);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withBackgroundColor(@NotNull Color color) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(color);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withFrameSize(int width, int height) {
            checkContainerSize(width, height);
            int x = (maximumWindowBounds.width - width) / 2;
            int y = (maximumWindowBounds.height - height) / 2;
            frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height); // implicit frame centering
            return this;
        }

        private void getAndAddToPane(@NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            JComponent textField = componentSupplier.get();
            frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        }

        private void getAndAddToPane(@NotNull String position, @NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            JComponent textField = componentSupplier.get();
            frame.getContentPane().add(position, textField);
        }

        public UIBuilder withDefaultCloseOperation(int windowConstant) {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(windowConstant);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withMenuBar(@NotNull Supplier<JMenuBar> menuBarSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(menuBarSupplier);
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBarSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withResizable(boolean isResizable) {
            frame.setResizable(isResizable);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withLocationRelativeTo(JComponent component) {
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(component);
            return this;
        }

        public void visualize() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static class ComponentBuilder {
        private JComponent component;

        public ComponentBuilder(@NotNull Supplier<JComponent> panelSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(panelSupplier);
            this.component = panelSupplier.get();
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withBorder(@NotNull Supplier<Border> borderSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(borderSupplier);
            component.setBorder(borderSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withSize(int width, int height) {
            checkContainerSize(width, height);
            component.setSize(width, height);
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withComponent(@NotNull String position, @NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            Stream.of(position, componentSupplier).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
            component.add(position, componentSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withComponent(@NotNull Supplier<JComponent> componentSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(componentSupplier);
            component.add(componentSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withVerticalScrollBarPolicy(int verticalScrollbarPolicy) {
            makeComponentScrollableAsNeeded();
            ((JScrollPane) component).setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(verticalScrollbarPolicy);
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(int horizontalScrollbarPolicy) {
            makeComponentScrollableAsNeeded();
            ((JScrollPane) component).setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(horizontalScrollbarPolicy);
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withPreferredSize(@NotNull Dimension preferredSize) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(preferredSize);
            component.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            return this;
        }

        public ComponentBuilder withLocation(int x, int y) {
            component.setLocation(x, y);
            return this;
        }

        private void makeComponentScrollableAsNeeded() {
            if (!(component instanceof JScrollPane)) {
                component = new JScrollPane(component);
            }
        }

        public JComponent build() {
            return component;
        }
    }

    public static class MenuBarBuilder {
        private final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        public MenuBarBuilder withMenu(@NotNull Supplier<JMenu> menuSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(menuSupplier);
            menuBar.add(menuSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public JMenuBar build() {
            return menuBar;
        }
    }

    public static class MenuBuilder {
        private final JMenu menu;

        public MenuBuilder(String menuName) {
            menu = new JMenu(menuName);
        }

        public MenuBuilder withMenuItem(@NotNull Supplier<JMenuItem> menuItemSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(menuItemSupplier);
            menu.add(menuItemSupplier.get());
            return this;
        }

        public JMenu build() {
            return menu;
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Have you considered to use [`lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) to avoid writing boiler-plate code?

Comment: @PeterCsala as you may see from the code, I actually do use Lombok, notice `@RequiredArgsConstructor` (though, I didn't see many opportunities to employ its capabilities in this particular project)

Comment: How about [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder), or [`@SneakyThrows`](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows)?

Comment: @PeterCsala my builders are not builders in the common sense and not the ones Lombok generates. As for `@SneakyThrows`, I used it in other projects, but I decided to go with my own approach here

Comment: I think that builders are great if you have to create complex products, or when you want to e.g. use it instead of copy constructors. But for, for instance, the `MidiEvent` I really don't see the point. What is different from simply calling the constructor? This is not just seeing things of a nail, this is making up things to nail down.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you can mess up the order of arguments pretty easily since they are all ints

Comment: Hmm, as long as you name your variables and use constants instead of literals I'd still argue that that is not enough of a reason alone. That said, the reason is not incorrect, so maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry if I'm trailing off towards the end, I might have misunderstood your initial premise slightly.

---

> What do you think?

Ugh...the whole Lambda-based DSL approach is something Spring does, and it **never** is as cool as everyone thinks it is. Overall, my go-to advice for DSLs is "Don't do it". If you need them (you'll know), then do a **real** language, and do not try to "emulate" it in an existing one.

---

`UIUtil` isn't a "utility class" at all, it's you *main* class to start everything. The name should be better. Ideally, all these methods might be in `UIBuilder` itself.

```java
UIBuilder.newBuilderWithLayout( //...
```

```java
UIComponentBuilder.newBuilder()
```

---

```java
UIUtil.getUIBuilderWithLayout(() -> null)
```

Why do I need to return `null`? Why can I not pass `null` to begin with? Why can I not skip it at all?

---

```java
.withBorder(() -> new LineBorder(Color.BLACK))
```

This seems overly verbose compared to how it would look in "normal" Swing code:

```java
component.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

---

```java
.withComponent(() -> UIUtil.getComponentBuilder(() -> {
        var leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        return leftPanel;
})
```

Here you're suddenly mixing your approach with "normal" Swing code.

Good APIs work on the principle of least surprises, they always work, behave and look the same. Not to mention that for some reason you need to "stack" your classes in the call.

---

Overall, your helper class seems overly verbose, complex, and the indentation of the code will increase and increase the more complex your GUI tree grows, moving interesting bits off the right edge eventually. Sometimes new components are returned directly, sometimes they need to be declared, sometimes they are declared as fields (I guess? Some declarations seem to be missing). And I'm not a fan of programming solutions that make me use many non-letter characters, for me it's comparable to having to remember arcane incantations, because most the time my IDE can't help me with those.

Let's get back to your initial premise:

> Swing code may be hard to read. As is, it's not inherently visually modular, and component composition is not immediately clear.

I agree with you if we look at this:

```java
    @Override
    public void createGUI() {
        JFrame notes = new JFrame("Notes");
        notes.setSize(960, 600);
        notes.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        left.setSize(320, 600);
        left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        filterPanel.add(new JLabel("Filter:"));
        filter.setColumns(20);
        filterPanel.add(filter);
        filterPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 40));
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        list.setFixedCellWidth(260);
        listPanel.setSize(320, 470);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 410));
        listPanel.add(scrollPane);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        add.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
        buttonPanel.add(add);
        del.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
        buttonPanel.add(del);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        left.add(filterPanel);
        left.add(listPanel);
        left.add(buttonPanel);
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setLayout(null);
        right.setSize(640, 600);
        right.setLocation(320, 0);
        right.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        titleLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 20);
        title.setBounds(60, 5, 555, 20);
        textLabel.setBounds(20, 4, 50, 130);
        textBox.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        textBox.setBounds(20, 80, 595, 410);
        save.setBounds(270, 535, 80, 25);
        label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        label.setBounds(100, 240, 500, 100);
        right.add(label);
        right.add(titleLabel);
        right.add(title);
        right.add(textLabel);
        right.add(textBox);
        right.add(save);
        notes.setLayout(null);
        notes.getContentPane().add(left);
        notes.getContentPane().add(right);
        notes.setResizable(false);
        notes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        notes.setVisible(true);
    }
```

That is hard to follow and read. But the code with your API seems much more complex.

Indeed, creating a GUI from scratch as given in your example would be quite some code. But it's quite doable (I've ignored some fanciness...like margins or borders):

```java
JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel();
filterLabel.setText("Filter:");

JTextField filterTextField = new JTextField();

JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
filterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
filterPanel.add(filterLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
filterPanel.add(filterTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JList<String> list = new JList<>();

JButton addButton = new JButton();
addButton.setText("Add");

JButton removeButton = new JButton();
removeButton.setText("Remove");

JPanel listActionPanel = new JPanel();
listActionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
listActionPanel.add(addButton);
listActionPanel.add(removeButton);

JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
listPanel.add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
listPanel.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
listPanel.add(listActionPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel();
titleLabel.setText("Title:");

JTextField titleTextField = new JTextField();

JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
titlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
titlePanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
titlePanel.add(titleTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JLabel textLabel = new JLabel();
textLabel.setText("Text:");

JTextArea textTextArea = new JTextArea();

JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
textPanel.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
textPanel.add(textTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JButton saveButton = new JButton();
saveButton.setText("Save");

JPanel detailsActionPanel = new JPanel();
detailsActionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
detailsActionPanel.add(saveButton);

JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
detailsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
detailsPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
detailsPanel.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
detailsPanel.add(detailsActionPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
mainPanel.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now that is quite a wall, but it is not *that* much code. Some good variable names, some empty lines, and it is readable. If we would want to improve that code, without creating a full new API, we could always split it into functions:

```java
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(createListPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
mainPanel.add(createDetailsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

If we apply a rule-of-thumb and not create such a function for every single component, the code becomes very readable and well structured very quickly. If you don't want to have those "create" functions in your class, push it to a nested, private class.

So, if Swing code isn't *that bad* to begin with, how can we improve that? There are **many** frameworks trying to answer that question, with different approaches each. The best approach is to **not** try to create a general-purpose framework, you **will** lose your self in cornercases and the API will never that clean as you want it. If you want to improve this code, take the same approach as the article in your link, serve *specific use-cases*.

For example, I'm doing everything with `BorderLayout` because, frankly, layouts in Swing are the horror. (Shameless plug warning) The [JVx application framework]([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JVx_(Framework\)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JVx_(Framework%5C))) does have custom layouts which are just *right*. So, let's start with that instead. Maybe we could do a "labeled" `Component`?

Before:

```java
JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel();
filterLabel.setText("Filter:");

JTextField filterTextField = new JTextField();

JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
filterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
filterPanel.add(filterLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
filterPanel.add(filterTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

After:

```java
LabeledComponent = new LabeledComponent()
        .withLabel("Filter:")
        .withComponent(new JTextField());
```

That would cut as some slack. We can even reuse it for the large text-area on the right:

```java
LabeledComponent = new LabeledComponent()
        .withLabel("Filter:")
        .withComponent(new JTextField())
        .placeLabelAboveComponent();
```

Or we could define ourselves a custom `ActionBar`.

Before:

```java
JButton addButton = new JButton();
addButton.setText("Add");

JButton removeButton = new JButton();
removeButton.setText("Remove");

JPanel listActionPanel = new JPanel();
listActionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
listActionPanel.add(addButton);
listActionPanel.add(removeButton);
```

After:

```java
ActionBar listActionBar = new ListActionBar()
        .withAction("Add", handlerGoesHere)
        .withAction("Remove", handlerGoesHere)
```

You see where I'm getting at? Such helper classes would also have the upside of being able to support instant-changes, like adding buttons at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Let me clear some of the confusion that you may have experienced. **1.** I don't think `UIUtil` qualifies for a main class. It provides helper functionality related to some specific aspect of making an application without being tied to a specific use case (building UI). That sounds like a utility class to me. Although I agree that the nested classes may be better off outside of the `UIUtil` class because their logic may be considered a bit too complex for a nested class

Comment: **2.** *Why do I need to return null?* It's because `LayoutManager` may require "building", i.e. more than one statement (`GridLayout` is one such example, think gaps and so on). Having to put `() ->` in front of your `null` (if you want a `null` layout for some reason) is, in my opinion, a reasonable price to pay for the additional flexibility it provides. The same goes for `Border`

Comment: **3.** *Here you're suddenly mixing your approach with "normal" Swing code.* It's just that `UIBuilder` accepts a `contentPane` `Supplier`, and since all `Supplier`s have the same erasure, I can't overload the constructor and add another one. At the same time, I can't set a layout with a regular setter since it would have to be the very first setter in a chain which I can't control (only beg a user in a javadoc, "Please don't set a layout after adding some components"). `ComponentBuilder` doesn't have such a limitation: you can easily build and add a component's layout in the same...

Comment: ...`Supplier` block as the one you use to supply the component itself. **4.** *the indentation of the code will increase and increase the more complex your GUI tree grows, moving interesting bits off the right edge eventually* It doesn't have to. Just like in React, you can develop components independently and then just plug them in. Each component would have a reasonable level of indentation or else be split into multiple components (or rather, *component suppliers*)

Comment: **5.** *But it's quite doable* Just because you added some new lines, your code doesn't become modular. It's still a "wall". If you split it into functions, you get many smaller walls, but you don't solve the actual problem. Besides, nothing stops you from writing components in any order (as long as it compiles). In my framework, you can list and build components in any order only if they are sibling components. Moreover, in regular swing code, you *must* allow some interweaving, at least because you need to add all components explicitly after building them. Such code is harder to read...

Comment: ...even with blank lines. It's also harder to imagine the actual UI since it represents logic but not layout. I offer a twofer: get logic, get layout for free (kinda). **6.** I'm not familiar with JVx, but isn't it in some ways what I was trying to do? `withComponent()` definitely rings a bell